# How do you make the wishbone break easier?

Tags: food-science

Real simple.  Kids love breaking the wishbone from a turkey or chicken.  What do I need to do so that the wishbone has a nice crack (more brittle) when they are pulling it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you dry it.

If you want your kids to be able to snap the wishbone on the spot, save one ahead of time from the *last* chicken or turkey.

Comment: We dry it out and leave it for 3-4 days and still most of the time it isn't an easy break, especially for the really young ones (wet break).

Comment: It's just not long enough for the bone to embrittle.  Don't forget it's not just water, but oils and gelatin. I think we've hung ours for a few weeks or more.

Comment: Anything that would reduce that time?

Comment: Do you have a dehydrator like for making dried fruit? Or how about low heat in your oven until it's hardened.

Comment: No don't own a dehydrator.  So looking at 3 weeks?

Comment: Or your oven...I never had a wishbone time constraint before